# How to configure DS.RESTAdapter in the latest version of ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to upgrade an ember js app and running into an issue where the `DS.RESTAdapter` is missing the `configure` method in the latest version of ember js. I do not see any documentation on what is the replacement for this. Does anyone know equivalent function that can be called to configure the RESTAdapter in latest version of ember js >= 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I hope i get your all question. this is how i did.

install [Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data)

`ember new ember-quickstart`

`ember g model product`

```
//app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'v0',
    host: 'YOUR-SERVER-URL',
    headers: {
        "API_KEY": "secret key",
        "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
    }
});



//app/router/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('product');
    }
});
```